# Is structural formula of 3-butanol possible?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Recently in my question paper.There was question asking me to draw the structural formula of 3-butanol.
Is the formula of 3-butanol possible?

Comment: No. There is only 1-or 2-butanol because the naming conventions dictates that you give the funcctional group the lowest possible number, so it is for example 1-butanol not 4-butanol.

Comment: I could tell you the structure, but IUPAC would have to kill me. ;-)

Comment: 3-butanol has an umambiguous structure, but by convention, we choose not to allow that name to reduce the possible names for a compound.

Comment: did it actually say "3-butanol" or was it "tert-butanol"? tert-Butanol (or t-butanol) is short for "tertiary butanol" which literally translates to "third butanol", so it could be mistranslated as "3-butanol" if your text is a translation. In any case, I would assume they mean t-butanol.

Comment: If tert-butanol, then of course it's 2-methylpropan-2-ol.  One carbon atom and then three methyl groups and a hydroxyl group joined to it.

Answer (score 3):

Formally, the structural formulas of n-butanol, n=1,2,3,4 are possible, similarly as n-ethanol, n=1,2.

But due the symmetry, there is redundance, as 4-butanol is identical to 1-butanol, 3-butanol to 2-butanol and 1-ethanol to 2-ethanol. Therefore IUPAC rules use just 1-butanol, 2-butanol and ethanol.

Using eventually 3-butanol for tertiary butanol ( or t-butanol ) aka 2-methyl-2-propanol is incorrect.